# use image/media/binary file for directory index (or pretty URLs for images/media)

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

for most web/http servers, the default is to return a file of the name `index.{html,php}` if a directory is specified in a path and contains the index file.

i am wondering if it is possible to return an image or some other content instead of the index file?  e.g. for this directory structure

```
releases
releases/album/
releases/album/covers/
releases/album/covers/front/index.jpeg
releases/album/covers/front/index.pdf
releases/album/covers/front/index.png
releases/album/covers/back/index.jpeg
releases/album/covers/back/index.pdf
releases/album/covers/back/index.png
```

the URL

```
http://server.org/releases/album/covers/front
```

would return the `index.jpeg` image in the `front` folder. thus, JPEG files are the default if no format is specified. then, the URL

```
http://server.org/releases/album/covers/front/pdf
```

would return the `index.pdf` version located in that folder, and likewise for

```
http://server.org/releases/album/covers/front/png
```

the `index.png` file. ditto for the `back` folder.  you get the idea ;)

also, i would like the actual `index.*` to not be accessible. thus the resources are only available through pretty/directory URLs.

this is a static site so i would prefer to solve this using `htaccess` configuration only. however, i am open to server side scripting (e.g. node.js, PHP) solutions as well.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only the `album` part of the URL varies, you can use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Block direct index requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /releases/[^/]+/covers/front/((pdf|png)/)?index\.(jpeg|pdf|png)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Resolve pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^(releases/[^/]+/covers/front)/?$ /$1/index.jpeg [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(releases/[^/]+/covers/front)/(pdf|png)/?$ /$1/$2/index.$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and apologies for the late reply. it works like a charm (i just made the question simpler and updated your answer to match)!

however, is there any way to make this .htaccess file a bit more generic/reusable? i.e. it would be more helpful if this .htaccess could be dropped directly in the "front" and "back" directories, instead of modifying the root .htaccess to have a reference to each dir.  i have been trying various changes myself but thus far no luck: i seem to be missing something very basic that prevents my local .htaccess rules from ever matching.

thanks again.

Comment: apologies for the delay in accepting your answer. i did not think that the clarified question's requirements were quite different at all, and thanks to your answer i was able to come up with a more generic solution which i will post. regardless, your solution definitely was 90% of the solution. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

i would just like to add a more generic/reusable version of @Ravi Thapliyal's solution:

```
RewriteEngine on

# block direct index file image requests in current directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ ?index\.(jpeg|pdf|png)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Resolve pretty URLs in current directory
# by default return JPEG version
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.jpeg [NC,L]
# accept either jpg or jpeg for JPEG version
RewriteRule ^/?(jpg|jpeg)/?$ index.jpeg [NC,L]
# for other types, return appropriate 
RewriteRule ^/?(pdf|png)/?$ index.$1 [NC,L]
```

now these rewrite rules can be dropped in any directory to make that directory serve index.{jpeg,jpg,png,pdf} image files as described in the original question (i.e. with pretty URLs).  for the the particular directory structure defined in the question, this would mean placing these rules in an .htaccess file in both the `releases/album/covers/front/` and `releases/album/covers/back/` directories.

once again, thanks to @Ravi Thapliyal who did the bulk of the work on answering the question.